# Как добавить фото на yii2 advanced

Tags: yii2

Как мне при добавлении информации в БД прикрепить фото? Вот как выглядит моя форма подскажите что ещё нужно изменить чтобы добавлялась информация и прикреплялось с ней фото в БД,

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model app\models\Serial */
/* @var $form yii\widgets\ActiveForm */
?>

<div class="serial-form">

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'Name')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'Name_Original')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input $model="img_serial" type="file">
</form>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'Discription')->textarea(['rows' => 6]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'Genre')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

         <?php
    $date_arr = [];

    for ($i = 1985; $i < 2020; $i++){
        $date_arr[$i] = $i;
    }
    ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'God')->dropDownList($date_arr)?>


    <?= $form->field($model, 'Nachalo')->dropDownList($date_arr)?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'Konec')->dropDownList($date_arr)?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'Status')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>


    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton('Добавить', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы прикрепить фото, это фото сначала необходимо загрузить на сервер и сохранить информации в базе данных. Для этого создаем таблицу images с полями id, name, ext (например). Затем контроллер с экшенами и вьюшками, для работы с файлами. Также нужен будет виджет типа такого http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/index.html

Когда научились загружать, сохранять и удалять файлы, теперь можно приступить к реализации механизма привязки файла к сущности (новости, например). Чтобы связать две разные сущности (файл и новость), необходимо воспользоваться промежуточной таблицей news_images. В этой таблице обычно три поля: id, entity_id, bind_id.

Теперь при сохранении модели сущности, необходимо сохранить в промежуточную таблицу id этой сущности и id из таблицы images.

Реляция на получение данных фото будет выглядеть приблизительно так:

```
public function getImage()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Images::class, ['id' => 'id'])
        ->viaTable('news_images', ['bind_id' => 'entity_id']);
}
```

Когда научились привязывать фото к сущности, необходимо позаботиться о целостности данных. При удалении сущности или фотки из БД, необходимо удалить запись из связующей таблицы.

Comment: За ответ Вам большое спасибо но теперь появилось ещё больше вопросов,для того чтобы загрузить фото нужно отдельно создать таблицу если есть таблица  в БД в которую добавляется информация без фото,но когда добавил поле image в таблице и в форме добавил часть кода добавления картинки перестала добавляться информация,возможно не правильно я задал вопрос но вот пример который мне нужно создать http://serials.fruckt.pp.ua/admin/login пароль 12345 всё без картинки у меня работает как-же сделать чтобы добавлялось с картинкой?есть возможность связатся с Вами по скайпу и решить этот вопрос???